# How to make an append item always visible in v-select vuetify

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, vuetify.js, v-select

I have a vuetify v-select dropdown.
Inside I made a slot #append-item in which I have a button "validate"
I want the button to always be visible when I scroll inside the dropdown.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wrap your button with a div having the `append` class name :

```
 <template #append-item>
              <div class="append">
                <v-btn color="primary">valider</v-btn>
              </div>
 </template>
```

that class should have the following css rules :

```
.append{
  position:sticky;
  bottom:8px;
  width:100%;
  display:flex;
  justify-content :center;
  background :white;
  
}
```

**[LIVE DEMO](https://codepen.io/boussadjra/pen/xxERwZm)**

Comment: save my day, thx!

Answer (score 2):

I added this style to my "validate" button and it worked:

```
.append {
  position: sticky;
  bottom: 0;
  background: white;
}


    <template #append-item>

      <div class="append">
        <v-btn color="primary">
          Validate
        </v-btn>
      </div>
    </template>
```